# How to add indent even for starting line of paragraph?

Tags: packages, indentation, paragraphs, ieee-style

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\title{\normalfont{Technical Report: Loren Ipsum}} 
\author{{Alex Murphy}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Introduction} 
\lipsum[1-3] % Dummy text
\end{document}
```

Above code generates below output,
[image]

But my supervisor forcing me to make indentation for all starting line of all paragraphs ( **even for the initial line of section/subsection** ). How can I do so?

Comment: Probably the `indentfirst` package could help.

Comment: That's a a typographical heresy!

Comment: @Bernard look at egreg's references in the linked answer. Whether or not to indent is highly language and community (or publisher) specific. Neither style is particularly heretical.

Comment: I don't  agree, because the aim of paragraph indenting is to draw the attention of the reader on a paragraph change. Just after a section heading, this is quite redundant. I know it is the French usage to add  paragraph indent even in this case, but some authoritative typographers think this is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

`\section` etc. use `\@afterheading` to remove the indentation for first following paragraph.  It uses `\everypar` which is often used for other purposes.  To allow the first paragraph to indent, simply disable `\@afterheading`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@afterheading}{}% or \let\@afterheading=\relax
\makeatother

\title{\normalfont{Technical Report: Loren Ipsum}} 
\author{{Alex Murphy}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Introduction} 
\lipsum[1-3] % Dummy text
\end{document}
```

Comment: indentfirst package is part of the core distribution and does this in fewer tokens (4) By disabling afterheading completely, you not only allow indent, but also allow page breaks after the heading which are probably unwanted.

Comment: I was going to delete this answer, but others might have the same idea.